# Match Values between Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've been having a hard time with this. This code helps me highlighting and matching the values between column J and G and then moving the value from column J into column H so that it can be beside the same value in column G but it is only working if it is in the same row. I would like it to work even if it is in a different row in column J. This image shows my problem.

[image]

```
Public Sub series()
    'Definición de variables (Definition of variables)
    Dim rango As String, valor As String, resultado As Range
    Dim primerResultado As String, cont As Integer
    Dim G As Integer, H As Integer, I As Integer, J As Integer

    'Solicitar información al usuario (Get information from the user)
    rango = "A1:XFD1048576"
    valor = InputBox("Ingresa el VALOR a buscar:")
    If valor = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' note 7 represents the 7th column ie G

    colG = 7
    colH = 8
    colI = 9
    colJ = 10


    cont = 0    'Inicializar contador de coincidencias (Initialize Find)

    'Primera búsqueda del valor dentro del rango (First search for value in the range)
    Set resultado = Range(rango).Find(What:=valor, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not resultado Is Nothing Then    'Si el resultado de la búsqueda no es vacío

        primerResultado = resultado.Address
        Do                              'Inicia bucle para hacer varias búsquedas
            If MsgBox("Resaltar Valor?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                cont = cont + 1
                resultado.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    'Cambia el color de fondo de la celda

            End If
            Set resultado = Range(rango).FindNext(resultado) 'Vuelve a buscar el valor

            If Cells(resultado.Row, colG) = Cells(resultado.Row, colJ) Then

        ' OPTION 1
        ' if value in column G has the same value that in column I
        ' move the value from column I to column H
        Cells(resultado.Row, colH) = Cells(resultado.Row, colJ)
        resultado.Value = ""

        ' OPTION 2
        ' if G3 has the same value that I5, move the value from I5 to H3.
        ' Note the use of -2
        ' Cells(resultado.Row, colH) = Cells(resultado.Row, colI - 2)

        ' now clear teh source cell
        resultado.Value = ""


        End If

            ' Display a simple message box.


        Loop While Not resultado Is Nothing And resultado.Address <> primerResultado
           MsgBox ("Valores Encontrados: " & cont)
    Else
        MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this with a formula in column H.

The formula in the example is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$8,MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$8,0))),"",INDEX($C$1:$C$8,MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$8,0)))
```

You would just modify the references. It looks in A1 to see if there is a match in C:C. If so, it puts the value in B1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now, check out your logic statement:
`=If Cells(resultado.Row,colG) = Cells(resultado.Row,colJ) Then`

That is why it's only working for the same row.  What you should do instead is loop through your Column J range.

Try this (Replace at `If Cells(resultado.ROw,G) = Cells(resultado.Row,colJ)` through the `end if` before "display a simple message box"):

```
Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range
Dim lastRow&

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lastRow, 7))
    cel.Select ' Comment this out when using, it's just here so you can walk through (with F8) and visually see the cel
    For Each cel2 In Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(lastRow, 10))
        cel2.Select 'Same here, re: comment
        If cel2.Value = cel.Value Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel2.Value
            cel2.Value = ""
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cel2

Next cel
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Both answers help me! Here is my code modified.

```
Public Sub series()
        'Definición de variables (Definition of variables)
        Dim rango As String, valor As String, resultado As Range
        Dim primerResultado As String, cont As Integer


        'Solicitar información al usuario (Get information from the user)
        rango = "A1:XFD1048576"
        valor = MsgBox("Deseas Mover los Valores?:")
        If valor = "" Then Exit Sub


        cont = 0    'Inicializar contador de coincidencias (Initialize Find)

        'Primera búsqueda del valor dentro del rango (First search for value in the range)
        Set resultado = Range(rango).Find(What:=valor, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)

        'If Not resultado Is Nothing Then    'Si el resultado de la búsqueda no es vacío

        ' primerResultado = resultado.Address
            ' Do                              'Inicia bucle para hacer varias búsquedas
                ' If MsgBox("Resaltar Valor?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                    ' cont = cont + 1
                   ' resultado.Interior.ColorIndex = 4    'Cambia el color de fondo de la celda

                ' End If
                ' Set resultado = Range(rango).FindNext(resultado) 'Vuelve a buscar el valor

            Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
            For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(lastRow, 7))
            For Each cel2 In Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(lastRow, 10))
            If cel2.Value = cel.Value Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel2.Value
            cel2.Value = ""
            End If
            Next cel2
            Next cel

            ' If Cells(resultado.Row, colG) = Cells(resultado.Row, colJ) Then

            ' OPTION 1
            ' if value in column G has the same value that in column I
            ' move the value from column I to column H
            ' Cells(resultado.Row, colH) = Cells(resultado.Row, colJ)
            ' resultado.Value = ""

            ' OPTION 2
            ' if G3 has the same value that I5, move the value from I5 to H3.
            ' Note the use of -2
            ' Cells(resultado.Row, colH) = Cells(resultado.Row, colI - 2)

            ' now clear teh source cell
            ' resultado.Value = ""


            ' End If

                ' Display a simple message box.


            ' Loop While Not resultado Is Nothing And resultado.Address <> primerResultado
            ' MsgBox ("Valores Encontrados: " & cont)
        ' Else
            ' MsgBox "Se encontraron " & cont & " coincidencias."
        ' End If
    End Sub
```